# Hearts change to question mark when I insert data into the database. How do I change the charset of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding

There is a video file named `♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4`. But as the file with this name is inserted into a SQL Server 2005 database the hearts change to `?`.

So the name turns into `?-You-Got-Me-?[www.savevid.com].mp4`.

I don't know how to change the character set of the database? How do I change the char set of my table so that it can over all the characters ?

It will be great if along with the command,*graphical method* to do so is included in the answer.

Comment: Are you storing the file name in a `VARCHAR` type or an `NVARCHAR` type?

Comment: using `nvarchar` will allow you to store char codes to your **heart**'s content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the character set of the database.  As long as you are using the NVARCHAR type, you should be good on the database side.  However, you have to make sure that however you get the data into the table takes Unicode into account:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(100) = N'♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4'
    , @NVAR NVARCHAR(100) = N'♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4'
    , @oops NVARCHAR(100) = '♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4'

SELECT 
    @VAR
    , @NVAR
    , @oops;
```

Returns:

```
?-You-Got-Me-?[www.savevid.com].mp4 ♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4 ?-You-Got-Me-?[www.savevid.com].mp4
```

The last declaration omits the N in front of the literal.  There are similar ways to mess this up in your front end.  Even if the DB stores Unicode, you have to make sure that everything between input and the DB, and then back out to your UI, handles multi-byte characters properly.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a CHARSET problem but a datatype problem in SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't have CHARSET as such like MySQL and [Collations are for code page, sorting and comparing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4272/630)

You need to use `nvarchar` to store unicode (basically non-latin) data properly.

Comment: I changed to nvarchar but still the data has question marks instead of heart

Comment: @saplingPro: **how** are you inserting?? If you're using string literals - are you prepending those with `N'...'` to mark them as Unicode??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely using `VARCHAR`, if possible changing to a `NVARCHAR` type should resolve the problem for new entries. If you cannot change the column type it may get more complicated.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8331/0)

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the field storing your filename from `varchar` to `nvarchar`.

For example:

Table:
FilenameId INT IDENTITY
Filename NVARCHAR(200)

SQL to insert data:
`INSERT INTO TestTable ([Filename]) VALUES(N'♥-You-Got-Me-♥[www.savevid.com].mp4')`